# send a mail if count (*) >0 in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have

```
PROCEDURE p_get_empdetails(pcu_scheme_info OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS  
BEGIN


    -- To Select scheme_ref,scheme_cat and quote_ref
    OPEN pcu_scheme_info FOR
        SELECT emp_ref
              ,emp_cat
              ,emp_quote_ref
        FROM emp_reset_id e
        WHERE estimated_quote_expiry_date <= lpcd_system_date
        AND q.quote_ref IN (SELECT DISTINCT qrc.quote_ref
                            FROM nb005 nb, 
                                 emp_reset_id e
                            WHERE nb.qteref = e.emp_quote_ref
                            AND nb.pcsstg <> 51);                
END p_get_scheme_details;
```

I need to send email if count is > 0

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM nb005 nb JOIN emp_reset_id e ON nb.qteref = qrc.emp_quote_ref
        WHERE nb.pcsstg=51;
```

Please help on this ?

Answer (score 1):

The question is vague. I'm assuming that you are using oracle 10g and above.If you are trying to send mail through PL/SQL, you can use `UTL_MAIL` package. You can try something like

`CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_test_mail
AS
  var_count NUMBER;
  CURSOR c1
  IS
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM nb005 nb
    JOIN emp_reset_id e
    ON nb.qteref   = qrc.emp_quote_ref
    WHERE nb.pcsstg=51;
BEGIN
  OPEN c1;
  LOOP
    FETCH c1 INTO var_count;
    EXIT
  WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
    IF var_count > 0 THEN
      utl_mail.send(sender => 'sendermail@senderdomain.com', recipients => 'receivermail@receiverdomain.com', subject => 'Your Subject', MESSAGE => 'Your Message');
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE c1;
END;`

There are some prerequisites to use `UTL_MAIL` package. You can find those details [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_mail.htm#BABFJJBD)